# How to combine two series of solutions into one?

Tags: trigonometry

I have an equation, like

$$\sin\left((\beta-1)\sqrt{\xi^2-\gamma^2}\right)\sin\xi=0,$$

with $\beta>1$ and $\gamma>0$. I've found two series of solutions, corresponding to roots of each of the $\sin$ factors:

$$\xi'_{n'}=\pi n',$$
$$\xi''_{n''}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\pi n''}{\beta-1}\right)^2+\gamma^2},$$

where $n',n''\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now I'd like to get a single explicit expression for $\xi_n$, where $n$ would numerate the equation solutions, so that $\xi_n>\xi_{n-1}$.

I can of course make some sort of an algorithm which would take finite number of steps to figure out the correct $\xi_n$ given some particular $n$. But I'd like to have an explicit expression, which would allow to just compute $\xi_n$ without any iterations or whatever. I.e. I want to have an explicit form for inverse of root-counting function.

How can I combine my solutions to achieve this? I'm mainly interested in enumerating such positive $\xi$ that $\xi^2\ge\gamma^2$, if this simplifies the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's study how root counting function for this equation behaves. For this, define:

$$
\begin{align}
n_1(\xi)&=\xi/\pi,\\
n_2(\xi)&=(\beta-1)\sqrt{\xi^2-\gamma^2}/\pi
\end{align}$$

and consider only the case of $\xi>\gamma$ (the other case is much simpler because only $\sin\xi$ will have zeros then).

The root counting function can then be defined as

$$n_r(\xi)=\lfloor n_1(\xi)\rfloor+\lfloor n_2(\xi)\rfloor.$$

If we neglect the floor operations, we'll end up with the function, which estimates the root count

$$n'_r(\xi)=n_r(\xi)+\Delta(\xi)=n_1(\xi)+n_2(\xi),$$

where $\Delta\in[0,2)$. Thus, $n'_r$ gives us an upper bound on $n_r$ with error of at most $2$ — due to fractional parts of $n_1$ and $n_2$.

Here's how the root counting function $n_r$, its upper bound $n'_r$ and lower bound $n'_r-2$ look for $\beta=2.9516$, $\gamma=24.25$:

[image]

Now we can use our estimating function $n'_r$ to find approximate inverse of root counting function, solving this equation:

$$\pi n=\xi_a+(\beta-1)\sqrt{\xi_a^2-\gamma^2},$$

for positive $\xi_a$ and getting

$$\xi_a=\frac{-\pi n+(\beta-1)\sqrt{(\beta-2)\beta\gamma^2+\pi^2n^2}}{\beta(\beta-2)}.$$

Since $n'_r(\xi)$ is an upper bound for root counting function, $\xi_a(n)$ is a lower bound for the inverse of root counting function.

Now that we have the lower bound for $\xi$, we have to determine which of the two series of solutions it is closest to. The candidate values for $n_1$ and $n_2$ are

$$n_{1c}=\lceil\xi_a/\pi\rceil,$$
$$n_{2c}=\left\lceil\frac{\beta-1}{\pi}\sqrt{\xi_a^2-\gamma^2}\right\rceil=\lceil n-\xi_a/\pi\rceil.$$

There're only two possible candidates for $n$, because the error $\Delta$ is strictly smaller than $2$. Thus candidates values for $\xi$ are

$$\xi_{1c}=\pi n_{1c},$$
$$\xi_{2c}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\pi n_{2c}}{\beta-1}\right)^2+\gamma^2}.$$

Now, since $\xi_a$ is smaller than both of $\xi_{1c}$ and $\xi_{2c}$, we can write $\xi$ as

$$\xi=\min(\xi_{1c},\xi_{2c}),$$

which is the explicit formula for $\xi(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Given two sequences of solutions $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$, we can collapse them into a single sequence by defining
$$c_n:=\begin{cases}
a_{\frac{n+1}2}&\text{if }n\text{ is odd,}\\
b_{\frac{n}2}&\text{if }n\text{ is even.}
\end{cases}$$
You can easily show that
$$c_n=b_{\lfloor\frac{n}2\rfloor}+\frac12[(-1)^n-1](b_{\lfloor\frac{n}2\rfloor}-a_{\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\rfloor}).$$
In your case the use of the floor function is unnecessary, as your sequences have natural extensions to $\{\frac{n}2\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. I can't think of many situations where the above form is preferable to simply expressing it as two sequences, though.

EDIT: I missed the condition $\xi_n>\xi_{n-1}$. In many cases that will be impossible, for instance if either $(a_n)$ or $(b_n)$ is bounded but contains infinitely many distinct points. It certainly doesn't look possible for this case, although it would depend on the specific values of $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: This doesn't seem to satisfy $c_n>c_{n-1}$.

Comment: Ah, I missed that condition. I'll edit.

Comment: Why do you think this is impossible for this case? Both sequences are unbounded and in fact they both grow almost linearly for large $n$. See also update about $\beta$ and $\gamma$ values.